# Yaakov's thigh and the side of the altar

Tags: words, hebrew, mishkan-tabernacle

When Yaakov wrestled with the angel [(Bereishis 32:25-26)](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.32.26?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), the angel was losing the fight, and touched the hipsocket of Yaakov, making it go out of the socket. The word for hip/thigh used here is יְרֵכ֑וֹ (יָרֵךְ).

My chavrusa told me that this word is also mentioned in [Shemos 40:22](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.40.22?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), where the Torah tells us that Moshe Rabbeinu put the table in the Mishkan:

> And he put the table in the Tent of Meeting, upon the side of the tabernacle northward, outside the veil.

Rashi, quoting the Targum, [explains](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Exodus.40.22.2?lang=bi&with=Exodus&lang2=en) that although the real plain meaning is "thigh" it also refers to the side of anything.

This got us thinking: this word is being used in connection with the Mishkan. Does the word יְרֵכ֑וֹ have a deeper meaning  in relation to the altar and the angel touching Yaakov's thigh? Maybe is the "slapping the hip out of its socket" a metaphor for something related to the altar? [(refer also the Midrash Lekach Tov)](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Lekach_Tov%2C_Leviticus.1.11.1?vhe=Midrash_Lekach_Tov_on_Torah,_Vilna_1884&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

Any commentaries that explain the connection between the two?

Comment: https://www.google.co.il/books/edition/%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99_%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%97%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA/Dg3uGHugAKkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%9A+%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%91+%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%9A+%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%91%D7%97&pg=PP140&printsec=frontcover

Comment: @TheGRAPKE thanks for bringing that Shaloh. Could you maybe elaborate what he exactly says?

Comment: I didn't go through the whole thing. He seems to say that Binyamin is the ירך of יעקב and of the כלי המשכן(i.e. the מזבח and the מנורה). A la Patterns in Time (Chanukah) I would imagine the general idea is that the בני רחל represent Yaakov's ability to "stand" (have a קיום) in עולם הזה, and this is what the שרו של עשו was פוגע (i.e. פגע בתמכין דאורייתא).

Comment: The Shelah doesn't draw a direct line, but he does seem to consider them related.